# Sort by multiple criteria with Kotlin

Tags: sorting, kotlin

We want to sort objects by three different criteria, the criteria with higher priority overrides the next one):

1. status field
2. time field
3. sort field

- status are enums and have a custom sorting, which we implemented by a comparator. (unknown, open, closed,)
- sortBy Field is an Integer and can be sorted accordingly
- time field can be null, we only want to sort the ones with null to the top and leave the remaining sorting as it is

**example:**

- Object1(status: open, time: 1, sort: 4)
- Object2(status: closed, time: null, sort: 1)
- Object3(status: unknown, time: 2, sort: 3)
- Object4(status: unknown, time: null, sort: 2)
- Object5(status: open, time: 1, sort: 5)

sorted:

1. Object 3 (status: unknown)
2. Object 4 (status: unknown, next item in the original list)
3. Object 2 (status != unknown, time: null)
4. Object 1 (status != unknown, time != null, sort: 4)
5. Object 5 (status != unknown, time != null, sort: 5)

we return the list the following way:

`list.sortedWith(statusComparator.thenBy { it.sort }`

What is missing is the sorting of items with time = null.
How do I sort the items with time = null to the top and leave the remaining sorting untouched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sort depending if the value is null we can... do exactly this, sort by checking if it is null:

```kotlin
list.sortedWith(
    statusComparator
        .thenBy { it.time != null }
        .thenBy { it.sort }
)
```

It works, because `false` is considered smaller than `true`. And it returns `true` for any non-null value, so all non-null values are considered the same.

We can join `time` and `sort` steps into a single one, by returning null if `time` is null and `sort` otherwise:

```kotlin
.thenBy { item -> item.time?.let { item.sort } }
// or:
.thenBy { if (it.time == null) null else it.sort }
```

It could be a little more performant, but I consider this harder to understand and less flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `Comparator` objects with `thenComparing` so you probably want to write a comparator for the time something like

```
val timeComparator = Comparator<YourObject> { first, second ->
    when {
        first.time == null && second.time != null -> -1
        first.time == null && second.time == null -> 0
        first.time != null && second.time == null -> 1
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

And then change

```
list.sortedWith(statusComparator.thenBy { it.sort }
```

to

```
list.sortedWith(statusComparator.thenComparing(timeComparator).thenBy { it.sort })
```